# sql server stats query

Tags: sql-server-2008, aggregate

I have a table with the following columns

```
source_title, country, language, source_url
```

I need to generate a query that will give me the following:

```
country, source_title count, percentage of sources
```

and

```
language, source_title count, percentage of sources
```

basically map the country to all sources and get the count and percentages of this mapping

not the row level data like

```
SELECT [source_id]
  ,[source_title]
  ,[source_url]
  ,[moreover]
  ,[country]
  ,[lang]
FROM [NewsDatabase].[dbo].[NewsSourcesMatch]
order by country
```

For example if there are 10 records where country is USA then

```
country    count(source_title)   % source_title
USA            10                    10/1000 * 100
```

sorry everyone here is sample data

**source_title  source_url  moreover    country lang**

Hadeland             http://www.hadeland.net        Hadeland    NORWAY  Norwegian

Business Wire   http://www.businesswire.com      Business Wire  UNITED STATES   English

Adelaide Now    http://www.adelaidenow.com.au   Adelaide Now    AUSTRALIA   English

MSNBC Local http://www.msnbc.msn.com    MSNBC Local UNITED STATES   English

UDN.com          http://forum.udn.com   UDN.com TAIWAN  Chinese

CBS3 Philadelphia   http://cbs3.com CBS3 Philadelphia   UNITED STATES   English

104.7 Edge Radio    http://www.1047edgeradio.com 104.7 Edge Radio   UNITED STATES   English

so there are four from UNITED STATES so shouldnt the total percentage be 4/7* 100

Comment: what do you mean by `percentage of sources and language` and `percentage of sources`? Can you provide some sample data and desired output?

Comment: the percentage of sources that match a specific country - like out of 1000 entries 10 match USA

Comment: to clarify: count of source_title per country, and what percent of all rows this count is. Ditto language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the OVER clause to span the entire dataset with COUNT to give total number of rows in the same query. Then you have both counts (per country and all rows) to generate the %

Should be something like:

```
SELECT  [Country]
    ,   [source_title_count] =  COUNT(*)
    ,   [source_total_count]  = COUNT(*) OVER ()
    ,   [source_percent]  = 100.0 * COUNT(*) / COUNT(*) OVER () 
FROM [dbo].[NewsSourcesMatch]
GROUP   BY [Country]

SELECT  [lang]
    ,   [source_title_count] =  COUNT(*)
    ,   [source_total_count]  = COUNT(*) OVER ()
    ,   [source_percent]  = 100.0 * COUNT(*) / COUNT(*) OVER () 
FROM [dbo].[NewsSourcesMatch]
GROUP   BY [lang]
```

If not, please add sample data and required output.

Or this?

```
SELECT  [Country]
    ,   COUNT(DISTINCT [source_title)) AS source_title_count
    ,   COUNT(*) source_country_count
    ,   100.0 * COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT [source_title)) source_country_count
FROM [dbo].[NewsSourcesMatch]
GROUP  BY [Country]
```

Can't test this (no SQL on this PC) but based on [MSDN OVER clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

```
SELECT  [Country]
    ,   [source_title_count] =  COUNT(*)
     --attempt 1
    ,   [source_total_count]  = COUNT(*) OVER (Country)
    ,   [source_percent]  = 100.0 * COUNT(*) / COUNT(*) OVER (Country) 
     --attempt 2
    ,   [source_total_count]  = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Country)
    ,   [source_percent]  = 100.0 * COUNT(*) / COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Country) 
FROM [dbo].[NewsSourcesMatch]
GROUP   BY [Country]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. One question, the source total count should that not be total records in table or how is that calculated. everything else is right

Comment: the COUNT(*) over() just gives you the number of rows in the dataset, no?

Comment: yes, but the total records in the table is 32000 and the source_total_count for each country is 204

Comment: @vbNewbie: see my last line please: define what you want more clearly with sample data. On the face of it, you're asking for a contradictory count.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, finally found the right combination using the over clause. Bless you for your assistance

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps:

```
;WITH T AS
(
SELECT  [Country]
    ,   Totals = COUNT(*)
FROM    [dbo].[NewsSourcesMatch]
GROUP BY [Country]
)
SELECT  [Country]
    ,   [source_title] 
    ,   [source_title_count] =  COUNT([source_title])
    ,   [source_title_pct]   =  COUNT([source_title])/t.Totals

FROM [dbo].[NewsSourcesMatch] A
    INNER JOIN
    T t
    ON A.country = t.Country

GROUP   BY A.[Country], [source_title]
```

And similarly for `lang`

Comment: Oh I appreciate your response, but not quite there...I would like the following: USA  5   5/1000

Comment: @vbNewbie, does the 1000 stand for total for USA or for the world?

Comment: country is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I was missing a Group By... try it now.

Comment: Ambiguous column name 'country'. Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 9

Comment: That was already corrected. I'd be surprised if this doesn't compile.